# how to update only one field in body request?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to update a release pipeline's description using the provide [Rest API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).

How should I send a 'Put' request in order to update a field?

I've tried to manually modify and capture the request using sniffer, it seems that my code does exactly the same.

```
$theBody = ConvertTo-Json @{description='Added a description'}


$instance = "tfs:8080"
$collection = "Collection"
$project = "myProject"
$releaseID = 1234
$apiVersion = "?api-version=4.1-preview.6"
$URI =  "http://"+$instance+"/"+$collection+"/"+$project+"/_apis/release/releases/"+$releaseID+$apiVersion


$res= Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put  -Uri $URI  -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $theBody  -ContentType 'application/json'
write-output $res
```

I'm getting an error message:

> the Id of the Release does not match the Id of the original release
>   resource. Make sure that you are trying to update the correct resource

Comment: try to list all your release pipelines with `GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0` and compare your id with the response id. Is it definitely the same like you use?

Comment: @MarTin Hey, I can perform a GET and even a Patch request using the code above , but it seems that in Put request , a single variable update , cant be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to get the release with the same URL but with `Get` method (and without body):

```
$release = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get-Uri $URI -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Then modify the description:

```
$release.description = "Added a description"
```

Convert the release to JSON:

```
$theBody = $release | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

And do the `Put`:

```
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $URI -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $theBody  -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: Hey , this is a nice solution and works fine .
Thanks.